# google webmaster showing 6 pages submitted 0 indexed, yet i can see them all there when i search in google?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I have a small 'brochure' type site with 6 pages, i can see them all the pages showing up in google when i search for my site.

But in webmaster tools under the sitemaps section it says 6 submitted, (the blue bar of the graph), but the indexed pages - the red bar is showing 0 indexed pages, even though they seem to be indexed ?

any idea why this is ? I dont really think its that important as the pages are still indexed, but it just seems odd.

---

UPDATE 9/3/12

having just looked in google webmaster its showing that there are 11 pages indexed, under the health > index status tab.. but under the optimization sitemap tab it shows 6 urls submitted but only 1 indexed ? please see images bellow

index status:
[image]

Sitemap status:
[image]

Comment: How long ago did you submit your sitemap?

Comment: about 8 weeks ago, it was did show up as indexed for a couple of days but then went. Ive done a couple of fetch as googlebots and submit requests but still nothing

Comment: 8 weeks it's a long time, it is a little bit strange.

Comment: Have you checked for sitemap and crawling errors. Is your robots.txt correct. Are the pages noindex?

Comment: Can you share your website URL for review; as it seems to be strange and can not say anything without review the website.

Comment: sure, the clients site is http://www.ll-i.co.uk

Comment: I have also the same problem. 56 pages have been indexed by google fetch option.but when I checked index status it shows nothing.

Comment: If you switch the view from Basic, to Advanced, does it show any additional information?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - i couldnt tell you the pages are indexed properly now

Comment: I'm glad this resolved itself for you.  I'm closing this question because there isn't enough information to provide a good answer and with the problem resolved you cannot provide for information.  If anybody else has this problem, they should feel free to ask the question again themselves and provide more information.